# Proper way to binding command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I'm trying to bind my own command to a button but nothing I try is working.

I got the window's `DataContext` bound via XAML but when I try to bind to my command IntelliSense is not seeing it, and the command is not executed. I tried to bind via code-behind but also met with the same result.

The window's `Binding` looks like this.

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource mainViewModelLocator}, Path=Commands}"
```

`mainViewModelLocator` passes a new instance of the `Commands` class.

The `Commands` class :

```
public ICommand GradeCommand { get; set; }

public Commands()
{
    LoadCommands();
}

private void LoadCommands()
{
    GradeCommand = new CustomCommand(GradeClick, CanGradeClick);
}

private void GradeClick(object obj)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Test");
}

private bool CanGradeClick(object obj)
{
    return true;
}
```

and `ICommand`:

```
private Action<object> execute;
        private Predicate<object> canExecute;

        public CustomCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
        {
            this.execute = execute;
            this.canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            bool b = canExecute == null ? true : canExecute(parameter);
            return b;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            execute(parameter);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My DataContext binding wasn't working.
IChanged it to:

```
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:ProgramName.ViewModel"
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:Commands/>
    </Window.DataContext>
```